# How to work volatile with multithread java

Tags: multithreading, volatile

Volatile provides reading and writing to program memory bypassing cache.  We should use volatile when there is a common resource, such as an integer variable
So, I did a little experiment.
First I had the following classes:

```
public class Main3 {
    static int j = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread1().start();
        new Thread2().start();
    }
    static int i = 0;
    static class Thread1 extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(i<5){
                System.out.println("thread1 i = "+i);
                i++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    static class Thread2 extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int val = i;
            while(val<5){
                if(val!=i) {
                    System.out.println("thread2 i = " + i);
                    val = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the first thread, the variable changes its value. The second thread monitors the change and displays the text on the console if it happened

i variable is a shared resource. And without volatile the program prints what was expected and cant :

```
thread1 i = 0
thread1 i = 1
thread1 i = 2
thread1 i = 3
thread1 i = 4
```

But, if i make this (add sleep to Thread2 class):

```
static class Thread2 extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int val = i;
            while(val<5){
                if(val!=i) {
                    System.out.println("thread2 i = " + i);
                    val = i;
                }
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

the program prints this and successfully finished:

```
thread1 i = 0
thread2 i = 1
thread1 i = 1
thread2 i = 2
thread1 i = 2
thread2 i = 3
thread1 i = 3
thread2 i = 4
thread1 i = 4
thread2 i = 5
```

So, if threads cache values, then why does sleep caching disappear with the advent of sleep?

Comment: have you debugged and checked that it is not a race condition?

Comment: Re, "We should use `volatile` when there is a common resource." No. We should _not_ use `volatile` unless we are so expert in writing multi-threaded code that we no longer need to ask. Until then, we should access shared resources from within `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: yes, it is, but my question is why it works like this

Comment: It works like that because it is _allowed_ to work like that. I'm assuming that's Java code in your example. The Java Language Reference manual lays out a number of promises about how your multi-threaded program will behave if you obey certain rules, but it doesn't say what might happen if your program _breaks_ the rules. FWIW, that's why it's virtually impossible to write software tests to catch thread-synchronization bugs. A program that passes the test on one particular day, one particular hardware platform, one particular operating system, could fail on a different day/box/OS.

Comment: P.S., The OS probably invalidates the processor cache for whatever processor it picks to run your `Thread2` each time that thread returns from `sleep()`.  But, you should never _depend_ on it to work that way.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you for explaining